# Node.js + OpenCV memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I have a problem with memory leaks (about 3-4MB each even cycle of this code) on node.js + opencv. I think readImage() method causes that memory issue.

How to free unused memory? I've tried release() function, but it causes segmentation error.

Is anyone already encountered this problem?

```
download = wget.download(src, path + filename, options);

download.on('end', function(output) {

  cv.readImage(path + filename, function(err, im) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (im.width() < 1 || im.height() < 1) throw new Error('Image has no size');

    im.detectObject('data/cascade.xml', {}, function(err, cars) {
      if (err) throw err;

      for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        car = cars[i];
        im.rectangle([car.x, car.y], [car.width, car.height], [0, 255, 0], 2);
      }

      im.save(path + '_' + filename);

    });

  });
heapdump.writeSnapshot('/var/log/node_' + Date.now() + '.heapsnapshot');
});
```